# Can TCP RST packet reduce the connection timeout?

Tags: linux, tcp

As a way to learn how raw sockets work, I programmed a dummy firewall which drops the packets based on the `TCP` destination port. It is working but the problem is that the client retries for quite some time until the time out is finally reached.

I was wondering if perhaps the client retries for so long because it does not receive any answer. In that case, would it help if the firewall replies with a `TCP RST` to the `TCP SYNC` messages from the client? If not, is there any way to force the client to stop retrying (not reducing the timeout time in the `Linux` but more, getting a specific answer to its packets which will make the client stop)?

Comment: Keep in mind that any response to the packet will reveal to the client the presence of the firewall. This is why firewalls are often configured not to respond.

Comment: Ok, I understand but I just wanted to try to learn more about TCP. The thing is that I am sending the RST messages back but nothing is happening, so I am not sure if they are wrongly built or if this is the normal behaviour of TCP

Comment: I would expect the client to keep trying with just a `RST`. A `RST` indicates an unexpected message in the conversation. Since the client is trying to start a new conversation, I would expect many clients will just try again. Most likely what you'd want to send is an [`ICMP` destination unreachable packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Destination_Unreachable).

Comment: I wonder if replying with a TCP fin would end the connection gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately, neither ICMP destination unreachable nor TCP FIN helped. In both cases (and also with TCP RST) I get a time out after around 31s (tcp_syn_retries = 4)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of your firewall as the same case as if the port were closed on the host OS.  What would the host OS's TCP/IP stack do?

[RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-36)  (original TCP RFC) has the following to say about this case:

> If the connection does not exist (CLOSED) then a reset is sent
> in response to any incoming segment except another reset.  In
> particular, SYNs addressed to a non-existent connection are rejected
> by this means.

You should read the TCP RFCs and make sure your TCP RST packet conforms to the requirements for this case.  A malformed RST will be ignored by the client.

[RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-103) also indicates that ICMP Destination Unreachable containing codes 2-4 should cause an abort in the connection.  It's important to note the codes because 0, 1, and 5 are listed as a MUST NOT for aborting the connection

> Destination Unreachable -- codes 2-4
>
> These are hard error conditions, so TCP SHOULD abort
> the connection.

Comment: The problem was that the TCP RST was not created correctly because I had an error in the checksum

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall is behaving correctly. It is a cardinal principle of information scurity not to disclose any information to the attacker. Sending an RST would disclose that the host exists.

There were firewalls that did that 15-20 years ago but there were frowned on. Nowadays they behave like yours: they just drop the packet and do nothing in reply.

It is normal for the client to retry a few times before giving up if there is no response, but contrary to what you have been told in comments, a client will give up immediately with 'connection refused' if it receives an RST. It only retries if there is no response at all.